# Can we add new columns to existing type 2 (slowly changing) table?

Tags: sql, scd, type-2-dimension

Can we add new columns to existing type 2 (slowly changing) table ?

Comment: `alter table add column`.

Comment: @Gordon i dont think the OP is asking to how to add but the possibility that after adding a column is it still scd2

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . I would say the question is quite unclear and incomplete.  I stand by the answer in my first comment.

Comment: Umm fair enough gordon.. but the reason i said was coz the OP's query includes Scd2

Comment: @gordon .. sorry for the confusion.. my question was more on how does it effect the current data as the surrogate key changes when a new column is added..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could because the updation of data to a new row would still be based on surrogate key.

So, still your data would be updated to a new row in case of redundant with a same surrogate key version even if u alter the table with a new column

Comment: Dont you think the definition of surrogate key will change.. and how do you backfill data when a new column is added in SCD2 .. what happens to the existing data

Comment: Not really the surrogate key will change the behaviour but it will change its value depending upon the data as it comes.